# Does a USB-C ethernet adapter have a higher latency than a regular ethernet port?

Tags: networking, ping, network-adapter, latency

Unfortunately, my new gaming laptop does not have a physical ethernet port. Will a USB-C to ethernet adapter produce the same latency(ping) as a physical ethernet port would? Also, how much CPU would the adapter use compared to a physical ethernet / WLAN connection?

Answer (score 2):

The difference in speeds should be minimal and the adapter contains its own chip
and will not use the CPU.

In the post
[Gaming laptops - ethernet port superior for latency vs ethernet adapter?](https://www.reddit.com/r/laptops/comments/677r55/gaming_laptops_ethernet_port_superior_for_latency/)
a curious user has tested ping on both and got
1.087ms on the built in, and 1.091ms on his USB dock.
However, his results are in no way guaranteed to apply to your hardware.

Comment: The latency of the NIC (either on-board, PCI(e) card, USB 3 or USB-C) is mostly negligible compared to that of the internet connection itself. It is somewhere in the order of 3 to 10 milliseconds, while the over-all connection is typically at least 100 milliseconds. That is a full order of magnitude higher.  Only older USB 1/USB 2 NICs could potentially have a significant latency problem as some of those can have 40 to 50 milliseconds in my experience.

Comment: @Tonny In Germany, on a DSL line I'm observing 18.6 ms ICMP roundtrip to a popular German web site. Between two different Ethernet devices I see a delta of 1.5 ms - which is 8 % of the whole latency. This still might be negligible for your use case, but certainly not for all use cases.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the exact USB-C Ethternet dongle.

For example, I've tested a few devices on a local 1 GBit LAN and a TP-Link UE300C 1 GBit USB-C dongle indeed showed the worst ping latency:

- integrated Ethernet port (Dell Latitude E7270 from ~ 2016): **0.47 ms** average latency
- Apollo Lake laptop with Lenovo Thunderbolt 3 Gen dock Ethernet port: 0.56 ms average latency
- TP-Link UE300C USB-C 1 GBit Ethernet dongle (ax88179_178a Linux driver): **1.9 ms** average latency

(tests done under Linux Fedora 36 + 37, using the standard `ping` command with a count of 100 packets, each)

It's possible that there are other USB-C Ethernet dongles that are lower latency and/or have higher quality drivers that are optimized for lower latency.

---

Recent laptops often come with Thunderbolt (>= 3) capable USB-C ports (sometimes not advertised because of missing/pending certification), such that looking for Thunderbolt Dock with an integrated (relatively) low-latency Ethernet port might be a good alternative in case you don't find a USB-C Ethernet dongle with suitable performance.

---

With any 1 GBit hardware the CPU usage should be negligible, nowadays.